# How to delete a row with a specific word in a loop with Python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, web-scraping

I want to delete all rows which contains "Scheduled" and export it to a new csv file. What am I wrong in my code? I haven't got any error message, it is running without problem, but nothing happens.

Here my code:

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name = soup2.h2.string
        datatable=[]
        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            temp_data.append(name)    
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
            datatable.append(newlist)
        print name
        output.writerows(datatable)

        def filter_unwanted_words():
            unwanted_words = {'Scheduled'}
            with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if set(line.split()).isdisjoint(unwanted_words):
                        yield line


        def write_output():
            with open('output2.csv', 'w') as f:
                f.writelines((line for line in filter_unwanted_words()))

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            write_output()

    resultcsv.close()
    time.sleep(10) 
    browser.close()
```

I tried with this def filter_unwanted_words, but it isn't working.

Datatable : [image: picture]

Comment: A few comments: Your indentation (probably just here) is a mess and you should share the datatable you get.

Comment: I updated my question with the output csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution. Consider reading this to a Dataframe with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[123,1,"Scheduled"],[345,2,"-"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df[2] != "Scheduled"] # filters with 2 being the column that has the value
df.to_csv("output.csv", header=False) # no headers
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    0       1   2
0   123     1   Scheduled
1   345     2   -
```

And data looks like this, "scheduled" filtered away:

```
    0       1   2
1   345     2   -
```

---

**A more general solution** that filters away all "Scheduled" independent of where they are:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[123,1,"Scheduled"],[345,2,"-"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].astype(str).str.contains(r"Scheduled", na=False) for col in df])
df2 = df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]
df2.to_csv("output.csv", header=False) # no headers
```

Comment: It sounds good, but what i have to write in data?
data = output.csv ?

Comment: output.writerows(datatable) --> this is my output.csv file

Comment: @tardos93 thing is.. with pandas you just put df.to_csv("filename.csv") and you don't need anything else (you can skip the whole thing about writing: with open()... writerows...

Comment: @tardos93 Another thing... there are countless of questions on SO and documentation about pandas so you most likely going to find the answer to almost any problem. It is really worth your time if you are working with Python+Tables

Comment: I tried this: 

df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
    mask = np.column_stack([df[col].astype(str).str.contains(r"Scheduled", na=True) for col in df])
    df2 = df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]
    df2.to_csv("output.csv", header=True)

It is working, and delete all rows with Schduled, but in the csv file it is getting a line number, and every columns end with "", why??

Comment: Docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html. Use **index=False**, and **header=False** or do you have header names? . When reading without header **header=None**

Comment: Yes, i have got a header, that's why it is True.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151246/discussion-between-anton-vbr-and-tardos93).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must put `if __name__ == "__main__"` outside the function `scrape`. Something like this:

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        name = soup2.h2.string
        datatable=[]
        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            temp_data.append(name)    
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            newlist = filter(None, temp_data)
            datatable.append(newlist)
        print name
        output.writerows(datatable)

    resultcsv.close()
    time.sleep(10) 
    browser.close()

def filter_unwanted_words():
    unwanted_words = {'Scheduled'}
    with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
         for line in f:
             if set(line.split()).isdisjoint(unwanted_words):
                 yield line


def write_output():
    with open('output2.csv', 'w') as f:
         f.writelines((line for line in filter_unwanted_words()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     write_output()
```

Comment: Yep, I guess so. You need to compare two files 'output.csv' and 'output2.csv' to see it ignores lines which contains 'Scheduled'.